# Get thumbnails for Array of Videos

Tags: swift, ipad, video, uicollectionview, avasset

I have found a few ways to get a thumbnail for a video using `AVAsset` However I want to get the thumbnails for an array of videos. I am populating the array from the applications documents folder on the iPad. This is how I get the array:

```
    func listVideoFiles(){
    let documentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
    let videoFolderPath = documentDirectoryPath.appending("/Videos")
    let videoFiles = FileManager.default.enumerator(atPath: videoFolderPath)
    while let file = videoFiles?.nextObject() {
        videoArray.append("\(file)")
        print("")
    }
    if videoFiles == nil {
        videoArray.append("No Videos Found")
        print("No Files")
    }
}
```

I am displaying the array in a `collectionView` like this:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cellA = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! VideoViewCell
    cellA.VideoCellLabel.text = videoArray[indexPath.item]
    gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = cellA.contentView.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.5137254902, green: 0.3764705882, blue: 0.7647058824, alpha: 1).cgColor, #colorLiteral(red: 0.1803921569, green: 0.7490196078, blue: 0.568627451, alpha: 1).cgColor]

    cellA.contentView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)

    return cellA
}
```

How would I get a thumbnail for each video and display it in the the corresponding cell?

Comment: I just want to let you know that if you are inserting the sublayer in the 'cellForItemAt' then it is going to insert a layer every time the cell is reloaded which is not so good according to me. Create a layer once at the cell level only instead of 'cellForItemAt'.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, what is a better way to do it? I actually won't be adding a sublayer once I get the thumbnails working. each cell will have an image background rather than a gradient

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
//Get the document directory path
    let documentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
            let videoFolderPath = documentDirectoryPath.appending("/Videos/")

//Generate the document directory enumerator
let videos = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last!.appendingPathComponent("Videos")
        let videoFilesEnumerator = FileManager.default.enumerator(atPath: videos.path).   //This will contain all the files in the videos folder
```

Use below function to generate the images from the videos in the 'Videos' Folder

```
func generateThumbnail(path: URL) -> UIImage? {
        do {
            let asset = AVURLAsset(url: path, options: nil)
            let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
            imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
            let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(value: 0, timescale: 1), actualTime: nil)
            let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            return thumbnail
        } catch let error {
            print("*** Error generating thumbnail: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return nil
        }
    }
```

You can have an image array as a property(here 'thumbImages') and fill the array as below :

```
while let element = videoFilesEnumerator?.nextObject() as? String {
     let thumbImage = self.generateThumbnail(path: videos.appendingPathComponent(element))
     thumbImages.append(newImage)
}
```

You have to take care of the optional values in the code as per your requirements are scenarios. After fetching all the thumbnail images you can directly set the images to the cells in the tableview.

Hope this helps.